# Is the function $F(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}\,\Bbb dt$ for $z$ such that $\operatorname{Re}z>0$ holomorphic?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

Is the function $F(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}\,\Bbb dt$ for $z$ such that $\operatorname{Re}z>0$ holomorphic?

I wanted to prove that it is analytic and find its power series:

$$F(z)={\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}\,\Bbb dt}={\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-zt)^k}{k!}\,\Bbb dt}$$

And if I could change the order of summation and integration it would be over, but it is a complex-valued function under the integral and sum, so Fubini’s theorem does not apply.

I tried this also:

$${\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{(-zt)^k}{k!}\,\Bbb dt}={\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}(-z)^k\,\Bbb dt}={\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}\,\Bbb dt\right)(-z)^k}={\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}\,\Bbb dt (-z)^k}={\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}(-z)^k\,\Bbb dt}$$

But the two last equations are suspicious (I changed the order in the second-to-last equation because function is non negative).

Can I do this? Is this function even holomorphic. How can it be proved?

Comment: $\int_0^{+\infty}t^k\mathrm dt$ diverges for all $k\ge0$, so your argument would not work even if you interchange the summation and the integral

Comment: what is the antiderivative of $e^{-zt}$ as a function of $t$?

Comment: Is there any issue concluding that $F(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ by computing the integral directly?

Answer (score 0):

They're power series about $z=0$ for obvious reasons. But things are well behaved for $z\in H=(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$.

Here is a prove that shows directly that the function
$$F(z)=\int^\infty_0 e^{-zt}\,dt, \qquad z\in H=(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$$
is holomorphic at any $z\in H$. This relies on basic integration theory.

Clearly $F$ is well defined in $H$ since  $f_{z}(t)=e^{-zt}\in L_1(0,\infty)$ for all $z\in H$.

Fix $z_0=a+ib\in H= (0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$.
Clearly $f_{z_0}(t)=e^{-z_0t}\in L_1(0,\infty)$.
For let $\delta>0$ so that $0<a-\delta$. For $h\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|h|<\delta$, $z_0+h\in  H$.

Notice that

\begin{align}
\Big|\frac{e^{-th}-1}{h}\Big|\leq\frac{e^{|h||t|}-1}{|h|}\leq \frac{e^{\delta|t|}-1}{\delta}
\leq \frac{e^{\delta t}+e^{-\delta t}}{\delta}.
\end{align}

Then

$$\frac{F(z_0+h)-F(z_0)}{h}=\int^\infty_0 e^{-z_0t} \frac{e^{-th}-1}{h}\,dt$$

Observe that
$$\Big|e^{-z_0t} \frac{e^{-ith}-1}{h}\Big|\leq \frac{e^{-(a+\delta)t}+e^{-a(t-
\delta)}}{\delta}\in L_1(0,\infty)$$

The conclusion follows from dominated convergence; furthermore,

$$F'(z_0)=-\int^\infty_0 te^{-z_0 t}\,dt$$

Applying a similar argument one obtains that

$$F^{(n)}(z_0)=(-1)^n\int^\infty_0 t^n e^{-z_0 t}\,dt$$

Which yields a power series about $z_0$ as

$$F(z)=\sum_{n\geq0} a_n(z-z_0)^n$$
where
$$a_n=(-1)^n\int^\infty_0 t^n e^{-z_0t}\,dt$$

Comment: dominated convergence theorem for complex $h$?

Comment: @romperextremeabuser: that is correct. If that is bothersome, one can always take sequences $h_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.